# Does it make sense to use GWT with the h5bp (html5 boilerplate) CSS reset?

Tags: html, gwt

I am confused with all theses technologies. I think that h5bp (http://html5boilerplate.com/) is a good practice for cross browser compatibility...but I also understood that GWT will enable JS and so it will be the same design for all browsers. Is that true (so I do not need to use the CSS reset) ?

Tkx,

Answer (score 1):

GWT converts your java code that targets browser to JS. h5bp helps to write an cross browser HTML page where you include your JS and/or CSS.
Tkx